# BigQuery JOINs between tables in different projects

Tags: sql, database, join, google-bigquery

I have datasets in two distinct projects.

I want to perform join of one table from a dataset in the first project to table in a dataset in the second project.

Can you provide an example of such a query?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can. You need to qualify the table name with project name, i.e. projectname:dataset.table
Here is an example of my joining one of my tables against table in publicdata project:

```sql
select sum(a.is_male)
from
(select is_male, year from [publicdata:samples.natality]) a
inner join
(select year from [moshap.my_years]) b
on a.year = b.year
```

**Update**: The syntax above is for Legacy SQL, with Standard SQL it becomes projectname.dataset.table, i.e.

```sql
select sum(a.is_male)
from
(select is_male, year from publicdata.samples.natality) a
inner join
(select year from moshap.my_years) b
on a.year = b.year
```

Comment: is this standard or legacy?

Comment: Updated answer for Standard SQL

Comment: How is the slots allocation works and cost attribution works in case of cross project queries? Would this be charged on the source (originating) project or the target project which has been referenced? Will slot's availability be an issue in this case?

Comment: Slots and costs are associated with the billing project for the query, which could be same or different from projects where the data is. You can explicitly specify billing project in bq cli with - - project_id command line option

Comment: Can we use SQL joins in big projects? is that a standard way to fetch data? assume that we have more than 2 million records data in tables

Comment: Worth noted that the data needs to be located in the same GCP region