# Table Value Function and Different Project Queries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 table value functions in 2 different projects. I can run these 2 individual queries and its working fine.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `project1.analytics_1.TableValueFunc1`('2022-01-01', '2023-02-02')

SELECT * 
FROM `project2.analytics_2.TableValueFunc2`('2023-01-01', '2023-01-02')
```

But when I union these queries, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `project1.analytics_1.TableValueFunc1`('2022-01-01', '2023-02-02')
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM `project2.analytics_2.TableValueFunc2`('2023-01-01', '2023-01-02')
```

I get this error:

> Table-valued function not found: project1.analytics_1.TableValueFunc1

I tried this solution but it's not working

[BigQuery JOINs between tables in different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821530/bigquery-joins-between-tables-in-different-projects)

Comment: Are the datasets (projects) in the same GCP region (zone)?

Comment: No, one in US and second in Europe

Comment: For each query all tables and all function must be in the same region. Please migrate all in one region. Or query the first part and export it to GCS and import it back to BigQuery in the other region/project.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. Both tables are used(its firebase tables means daily new tables are added).  Can I change the location of project/dataset (which include auto migration)?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing as auto migration of region zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to join 2 tables from different regions.

The solution is to use the [BigQuery data transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dts-introduction) to copy a dataset to another one (to the correct region).

The only option is to duplicate all the data in the dataset (not possible to select only a table) to another region (and therefore to pay the data storage and the inter region network traffic).

For more information about Moving datasets you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/move-datasets#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20transferring%20data%20between,Cloud%20Storage%20bucket%20into%20BigQuery.).